# Why can't I check my child TreeViewNode checkboxes programmatically?

Tags: winforms, powershell, treeview

Hello I am attempting to check child checkboxes in a TreeView like so:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $treeView -EventName AfterCheck -Action {
    $e = [System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs]$EventArgs

    if($e.Action -ne [System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewAction]::Unknown)
    {
        foreach($childNode in $e.Node.Nodes)
        {
            ([System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode]$childNode).Checked = $true
        }
    }
} | Out-Null
```

Which does in fact properly set the "Checked" property to true, but the tick is not displayed on the form.  I also have attempted setting TreeViewNode text and experience the same result.  I've checked the hash values on the .NET objects thinking that the event handler was firing from a separate runspace or working with copies of the objects but this does not appear to be the case.

Any thoughts on why the form isn't displaying changes to the objects from inside the handler?  My form's load handler is able to properly populate the TreeView, so why wouldn't I be able to modify it from the AfterCheck handler?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked to see if your object that you are displaying has a Refresh method or some such that needs to be performed to update it on screen?

Comment: I have attempted utilizing the Refresh and Update methods on both the form and control itself--all to no avail.

Comment: Hm, I looked up [TreeView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview(v=vs.110).aspx) and the Refresh method should definitely do what you want: **Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.** My only other thought is to perhaps try the InvokePaint method.